# Open a javascript advertising code when click on a another url link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is I want to open a advertisement but condition is .. when i click on data url

at that time data url opened also with another new window advertisement also open.

So how i write a code so open two page : one my content(data) page and another is

advertisement page..

Please give me a answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run an `onClick="function()"` and a link.

```
<a href="link1"><div onClick="openAd()"></div></a>

<script>
var function = openAd(){
window.open("ad");
}
</script>
```

Here I use `window.open()`, which does what it sounds like and opens a new window with the link.